# Eiffel shortest statement for object creation and result of function

Tags: eiffel

If I'd like to add a DATE_TIME to a logger for example I'd like to avoid creating a local variable for that.
Is there any similar statement as

```
create {DATE_TIME}.make_now.formatted_out ("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss")
```

which is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parenthesis expression can be used as a target of a qualified call:

```
(create {DATE_TIME}.make_now).formatted_out ("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss")
```